# How to check in .htaccess is the subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file, in which I rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
```

It makes `myproject.com/profile.php?username=iamuser` to`myproject.com/iamuser`

But what if I want to go to a folder, for example "images", when i write  `myproject.com/images`, it remain on profile.php as 'images' as a username

Please help. Thanks

Comment: That's obvious: if you rewrite everything, even images is rewritten. Probably, you could place your profiles under another name, like `myproject.com/profiles/$username`?

Comment: is anyway to use QSA or L?

Comment: No, `QSA` and `L` flags won't work  . You need the following  condition `RewriteCond  % {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` to avoid rewriting existing directories

Comment: Doing a root level catch-all rewrite like that, you are most likely going to have to define every single app, script, and directory (!-d) that should NOT be rewritten ahead of that line, so that it does not match on them. Which is a lot of work and planning if you are up to it. Maintenance becomes an issue too.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `RewriteCond` to check if the request URI belongs to any existing files / directories.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

`-d` tests whether it exists and is a directory. `-f` tests whether it exists and is a file. The `QSA` flag appends the query string if any of the original request. The `L` flag makes it the last rule to process. No other rules behind are processed if this rule matches.